# Is there a jQuery plugin that automatically tidies up HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery plugin (for a text editor) that will work to tidy up HTML code. I.e., if I have a code sample like this:

```
 <div><div>This is test code</div><ul><li>More Test Code HERE!</li><li>Even more</li></ul></div>
```

I would like the plugin to output something more like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    This is test code
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>More Test Code HERE!</li>

    <li>Even more</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there something like that available?

Comment: Is this quite a duplicate of the other question? That question colors the code for human consumption but it doesn't seem to fix the indentation of the code. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Correct. I don't need the syntax highlighting (it would be nice), but I need a formatter, like [Dirty Markup.](http://www.dirtymarkup.com/)